# WAMP server in windowss 7 safe mode

Tags: wamp

Because windows 7 crashed and gives me this msg: The application was unable to start correctly (0xc0000022). So i started win 7 in safe mode to just backup my project database, but WAMP server is not working and it's icon is red.

Is there any way to backup database or start WAMP.
So kindly help.

Comment: imho this should be posted to serverfault

Comment: Thanks Rishi. Asked http://serverfault.com/questions/410212/wamp-server-in-windows-7-safe-mode and done.